# How to update mongodb array item without race condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, atomic, race-condition

I have an update query that proved to be subject to a race condition, but I don't really know why.

Let's say I have a `stuff` collection in mongodb. I'm using numeric ids for the sake of clarity.

```
stuff: {
  _id: 123
  elements: [
    {
      _id: 456,
      value: 'foo',
    },
    {
      _id: 789,
      value: 'bar'
    },
  ]
}
```

Now I want to update the value on the `element` 456 that lives under the `stuff` 123.

I thought this was ok (I'm using mongoose, hence the `Stuff` class):

```
Stuff.update(
  {
    _id: 123,
    'elements._id': 456
  },
  {
    $set: {
      'elements.$': {
        _id: 456,
        value: 'foobar',
        something: 'else',
      }
    }
  }
)
```

This query, however, seems to be subject to a race condition. I can't really explain why, but I could prove that firing that request in parallel would mess up my data; in particular if I try to update both elements `456` and `789` at the same time.

- Is there a comprehensive reason of why this causes trouble ?
- Is there a way to fix the query so it becomes concurrent-proof ?

Thanks !

PS: in case that's of any relevance, I'm using Mongoose